# Style header with `width: 100%` without using the `position` property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML structure:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>header</div>
```

Can I make exactly the same thing *(like the result of code above)* **without** `position` property ?

Comment: Yes. By default element will have 'position:static`.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of `position`?

Comment: I know it is bad code, but can't you just make the div '100000000px' wide.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just be sure to set `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` on your `html` and `body` elements as well, because most browser stylesheets set non-zero default values for these properties:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>header</div>
```

Comment: @MartinAJ This issue is fixed for you now, correct?

Answer (score 1):

#### To debug, you can see...

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>header</div>
```

#### One soution could will be remove margin/padding from body.

(NOTE: if you are using bootstrap like `row` etc, you might have margin left or right for 15px, for that situation you might need use `xxx { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;}`

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>header</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, for every block element, since their default `width` is 100%. You can then also erase the width: 100%, and the top/left properties.

To get the same effect as in your example, just make sure to set `margin` to 0 for `html` and `body` , which sets their otherwise default margin to zero:

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
}
div{
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>header</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here by default browser (User agent stylesheet) applied a default margin to the body tag. So u can override the style of the body tag.

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>header</div>
```

Hope this is what you where looking for.